# How to discover if Microsoft Project 2016 is installed on a remote machine

Tags: powershell, windows-command-prompt

I've been trying to find a way to learn if Microsoft Project 2016 is installed on a remote machine.  The main problem I'm running into is that Microsoft has, at some point in the past, concealed or encapsulated the components of its installation into a facade that reads and displays the version of Office and not the components of the Office installation.

For example, we run mostly Office 2013 with some Office 2016 components (Project 2016 and Skype for Business 2016).  When I run the "Uninstall" path within HKLM (HKLM\software\Microsoft\Windows\currentversion\uninstall) -- which is what I've seen many people do -- this is the information I receive for about the Office install:

```
Microsoft Office 64-bit Components 2013
Microsoft Office 64-bit Components 2016
Microsoft Office Shared 64-bit MUI (English) 2013
Microsoft Office Shared 64-bit MUI (English) 2016
Microsoft Office Shared 64-bit Setup Metadata MUI (English) 2013
Microsoft Office Shared 64-bit Setup Metadata MUI (English) 2016
```

This is all informative but I need more information.  I specifically need to if MS Project 2016 is installed on the remote machine.

I've tried many suggestions but I haven't been able to find one that gives me the answer I'm looking for.

Is there a way to specifically find out if Microsoft Project 2016 is installed on a remote machine?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using a 32 bit version of MS Project, so you must look in the WOW6432Node:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Microsoft [provides a documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/miscellaneous/numbering-scheme-for-product-guid) that you can use to find the GUID of Office products in the "Uninstall" node.